# Who is this person and what is he holding from the Avengers: Age of Ultron trailer #3?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, avengers, character-identification, avengers-age-of-ultron

In this trailer (Avengers: Age of Ultron trailer #3):

There is this shot:

[image]

**Who is this person and what is he holding?**

Comment: Not sure about what he's holding, but the clothing seems to resemble [Baron von Strucker](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/vlcsnap-2014-08-04-21h24m50s235_4118.png) from the Cap2 post-credits scene.

Comment: Klaw? Black Panther?

Comment: Despite his name, Ulysses Klaw does not have claws in the comics; he has a prosthetic hand that shoots sound waves. Black Panther has fingertip claws. Obviously, that doesn't necessarily mean that it's *not* either of them, but it's less likely.

Comment: Grim reapers hand in the process of turning into his scythe? Considering his ties to Hydra and Ultron. Since his scyche was made by the tinkerer but upgraded by Ultron, and Ultron uses the mind patterns of his brother to create Vision, it could be the Grim Reaper.

Comment: Hot Toys has released photos of their new officially licensed Hawkeye figure, and it answers this question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The newly revealed, officially licensed [Hot Toys figure](http://www.hottoys.com.hk/productDetail.php?productID=291) confirms this to be **Hawkeye and his new Speed Loaders**.

We can see the claw-looking object in this shot of the figure.

[image: Hawk Guy figure]

The description of the figure details what weapons and accessories the figure includes.

> Weapons:
>
> - One (1) fully-opened purple and black colored bow
> - One (1) folded purple and black colored bow
> - **One (1) speed loader with nine (9) arrows**
> - Thirteen (13) individual arrows and nine (9) interchangeable arrowheads of different styles

and

> Accessories:
>
> - One (1) quiver
> - **One (1) pair of arrow speed loaders**
> - One (1) pair of sunglasses
> - Specially-designed figure stand with Hawkeye nameplate and the movie logo

(The listing of the item under both Weapons *and* Accessories is a bit confusing, but it only appears that the figure includes one single speed loader.)

Note: Technically without a face in the trailer, we can't yet 100% confirm that it's Hawkeye holding it, but it's his equipment, and the way that this trailer is cut, heavily implies that it is him.

Additional Note: While the specific shot from the trailer seemed to have been omitted from the final cut of the movie, there *was* a very similar shot during one of the battles. The scene confirms that the object is Hawkeye's speed loaders.

Comment: Wait, are you sure that's a photo of a *toy*? Not the actor? Good lord.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>**We don't know yet.**</strike> **It is Hawkeye, and he is holding a device that loads several arrows at once.**

Given the characters whom we know about, the most likely candidate is Ulysses Klaw - a villain considered to be one of the world's foremost experts on Vibranium.

The comics version of Klaw has a prosthetic hand, but it is usually out-fitted with a type of "sonar gun" that allows him to use sound as a weapon. The "Heroes Reborn" version of Klaw did indeed feature a prosthetic hand somewhat similar to the one shown:

[image]

**UPDATE:** This scene was featured again in the latest TV spot, and I was able to do a frame-by-frame shot of it. The item in question definitely appears to be either a prosthetic (one that replaces only the fingers and leaves the thumb intact) OR some kind of hand-mounted weapon. As you can see below, the thumb is clearly visible just before the item expands. This further leads me to believe that the person in question is Ulysses Klaw.

[image]

**UPDATE 2:** I was wrong. Completely wrong. Having now seen the movie, I can confirm that the person/scene in question IS, indeed, Hawkeye. The contraption we see extend from his arm is in fact several (9?) arrows that get fired together (at the same time) in order to hit different individual targets. However, I'll leave the answer mostly intact for historical purposes.

Comment: If you take a look at the bottom third of the shot in question, you can see a line stretching from bottom left to middle right. That's more than likely a bow string, and my money is on those being arrows, or at least something to fire from a bow. I reckon we are looking at Hawkeye there.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I thought the same, but if you watch, the body twists to the side a little as the item expands, yet the 'bowstring' never moves (which it would if the bow were being held in the other hand). This leads me to believe that it's either a cable or the edge of something.

Comment: The way [this new trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WM915QsOyI) is cut, it heavily implies that it's a piece of equipment being used by Hawkeye, whatever it is.

Comment: @Omegacron The bowstring and the bow you can see in the bottom-right corner move a bit.

Comment: @phantom42 agreed, the way it shows that immediately after Hawkeye gearing up. However, the clothing appears to be a Nazi/Hydra-style uniform and NOT the outfit Hawkeye is seen wearing. Still could be him, though, since that IS the "Hawkeye section" of the spot like you said.